# Python3: Remove \n from middle of the string while keeping the one in the end

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and stuck with this problem. I have a `multiline string`:

```
My name is ABCD \n I am 20 years old \n I like to travel
his name is XYZ \n he is 20 years old \n he likes to eat
your name is ABC \n you are 20 years old \n you like to play
```

I want to replace all `\n` with space but keep the sentence as it is.

The desired output is:

```
My name is ABCD I am 20 years old I like to travel
his name is XYZ he is 20 years old he likes to eat
your name is ABC you are 20 years old you like to play
```

I tried: `str.replace('\n', ' ')` but it gives:

```
My name is ABCD I am 20 years old I like to travel his name is XYZ he is 20 years old he likes to eat your name is ABC you are 20 years old you like to play
```

Which is not what I want. Can you please guide me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are there **always** two `\n` within each line ?

Comment: What is the exact format of that multiline string? Is it a python string literal using triple quotes like `text = """  (your string) """`? If that's the case, then you can't really do it. Python converts the `\n` to newlines just like the newlines after "travel" and "eat". They are indistinguishable. A fully working example would help answer the question.

Comment: @ScottC The number of `\n` is indeterministic.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, the format is:
`text = """  (your string) """`

Comment: @lediwa - You could use a raw string so that `\n` isn't converted into newlines. `text = r""" (yourstring) """` and then do `replace(r'\n', ' ')` (so that would be the two characters \ and n).

Comment: @tdelaney Thank you. it worked! BTW is there a way to convert normal string to a raw string? I will be getting the text from a remote server.

Comment: @lediwa - That's why I was asking the question. Strings literals are the quoted strings we type into a python script to generate strings. With a regular string, things like `\n` and `\t` are turned into newlines and tabs. But string literals are just how we as humans type them into the code. If you are getting a string from some other source, then its not a string literal and you have the problem that the `\n` in the _source code_ of the other remote script has already been converted - so you can't do the replace.

Comment: If you are showing us exactly the text you get from the other side - perhaps it was text typed into a text editor just like that - then those are still the two character \ and n, my raw replace example will still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to find the **newlines** (`\n`) that are surrounded by a **space** `\s`.

- The regex pattern looks like `r"(\s\n\s)"`

**Here is the example code:**

```py
import re

test_string = """
My name is ABCD \n I am 20 years old \n I like to travel
his name is XYZ \n he is 20 years old \n he likes to eat
your name is ABC \n you are 20 years old \n you like to play
"""

pattern = r"(\s\n\s)"
new_text = re.sub(pattern, "", test_string)

print(new_text)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
My name is ABCD I am 20 years old I like to travel
his name is XYZ he is 20 years old he likes to eat
your name is ABC you are 20 years old you like to play
```